# Is it possible to automatically mark broken links?

Tags: feature-request, broken-link, automation

People often post links to third-party sites as a reference or to provide further readings.

Over time, these links become stale and end up leading to 404 pages.  Is it possible for the framework to automatically check links on whether they are broken and mark them as such?

Or, allow for users to "tag links" as "broken" and once confirmed that they are broken, to mark the link with a broken link icon beside it?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130399/169101

Comment: @RobW I don't think it ever got really implemented.  https://www.google.com.au/search?q=%22we+detected+an+invalid+link+in+your+post%2C+please+correct+it%22&oq=%22we+detected+an+invalid+link+in+your+post%2C+please+correct+it%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.21105j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22we+detected+an+invalid+link+in+your+post%2C+please+correct+it%22+site:stackoverflow.com Only a few posts on META of a few years ago

Comment: @Michael It was implemented at some point. I discovered this feature last year when I saw this unusual user agent in my server's access logs.

Comment: @RobW see link in my previous comment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Automatically marking broken links would be great.

Asking users to manually mark a link for later confirmation isn't worthwhile.  If they have enough rep to edit, they could include an updated link or (in rare circumstances) edit to say it's broken.  In the latter case, or with much less rep, a comment works and notifies the poster — who has an incentive to fix the links in content attributed to them.

Comment: Yeah, I added the second question as an after-thought.  There obvious challenges that probably aren't worth while with regard to having other people flag links as broken.  What I really wanted to suggest is a way to automate finding broken links.  It should be feasible from a tech point of view, I think...

Comment: @Remus: It's probably a bit of work on the backend side of things, to do correctly, but I agree it would be helpful.

Comment: If we can get a little icon showing a crying unicorn next to all broken links, then I'm on board with this.

Comment: @Jon: I am sure there will be a userscript for exactly that available 6-8 minutes after this feature is implemented.

Comment: Your answers confirmed my original thoughts.  Is this how feature requests are done on SO? (through a "question" with feature-request tag attached)  Is there a better place to make these suggestions?

Comment: @Remus: Yes, posting a [feature-request] on meta is the right thing to do; however, the right people also need to see it.  You might edit to include better tags, which will also bring this to the front page and allow more people to see it (and vote on it); but I suspect this is a low priority feature, even if it is decided to be included.